# Magento2:If add custom discount with value higher than subtotal Then grand total is a negative number

Tags: magento2, checkout, coupon-codes

```
$subtotal = $quote->getSubtotal();    
if($balanceData>$subtotal){
        $balanceData=$subtotal;
        $this->_checkoutSession->setData('isGreaterThanSubtotal',$balanceData);
    }
$customdiscount = -intval($balanceData);
$total->addTotalAmount('customdiscount', $customdiscount);
$total->addBaseTotalAmount('customdiscount', $customdiscount);
$quote->setCustomDiscount($customdiscount);
```

[image]

Comment: Just check if your custom discount amount is higher than subtotal? 
`$customdiscount = ($customdiscount > $quote->getSubtotal()) ? $quote->getSubtotal() : $customdiscount;`